# Need a formatted a output from the following code

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get an array output as this `[[1, 26], [3, 16], [3, 17], [4, 27], [4, 26]]` from the following php mysql code

```
    include("db.php");

$villa = $_GET['villa'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT unavailable_date_from, unavailable_date_to FROM villa WHERE name = '".$villa."'");
$json = "[";
    while($results = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){

        foreach ($results as $field => $value) {
            $a = explode("-", $value);

            $json = $json . '[' . $a[1] .','. $a[2] .'],';
        }

        $json = substr($json, 0, strlen($json)-1);

    }

$json = $json . ']';

echo $json;
```

The current code give the following result: `[[03,08],[03,10][03,15],[03,20]]`

Can somebody tell me how can I add that one comma between the second and third array element

Thanks

Comment: @mujahid - That means clicking the checkmark next to the answer you accept as being most helpful/correct for your question. This gives points to the person who provided the correct answer.

Comment: at the top-left of the answer, you can find `tick` and you click on it, where the answer is most helpful.

Comment: And also you get +2 reputation, and the answerer will get +15 reputation. And please could you write the format that you are expecting answer.

Comment: @experimentX: I got the answer from konforce, thanks a lot for the information that you gave me

Comment: sure .. you are welcome. And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `$json = substr($json, 0, strlen($json)-1);` to be on the line before `$json = $json . ']';`.

It will look like:

```
if ($json != '[') $json = substr($json, 0, strlen($json)-1);
$json = $json . ']';
```

Kind of messy, but it will work. Edit: Using `rtrim` would be nicer:

```
$json = rtrim($json, ',');
$json = $json . ']';
```

Here's the full code:

```
$json = '';
while($results = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
    foreach ($results as $field => $value) {
        $a = explode("-", $value);
        $json .= '[' . $a[1] .','. $a[2] .'],';
    }
}

$json = '[' . rtrim($json,','). ']';
```

Comment: it give me following result: [[03,08],[03,10]][03,15],[03,20]]]

Comment: @Mujahid, See the full code edit. Perhaps you missed something.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, it working perfectly, thanks a lot, u saved the day

Answer (score 0):

for example add this:

```
$json = str_replace('][', '],[', $json);
```

before last echo line.

Answer (score 0):

The `$json = substr($json, 0, strlen($json)-1);` should be after the loop finishes and before the `']'` addition.

```
    include("db.php");

$villa = $_GET['villa'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT unavailable_date_from, unavailable_date_to FROM villa WHERE name = '".$villa."'");
$json = "[";
    while($results = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
         foreach ($results as $field => $value) {
            $a = explode("-", $value);
             $json = $json . '[' . $a[1] .','. $a[2] .'],';
        }
     }
if (len($json) > 1) $json = substr($json, 0, strlen($json)-1);
$json = $json . ']';
echo $json;
```

Comment: That will return `]` on an empty query.

Comment: @konforce: Oh, yes, you are right, it will break with empty query.

Comment: corrected it. Your second solution (with rtrim) is better though.